# Calling an anonymous function within another function without calling the parent function

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, recaptcha, anonymous-function

I'm trying to call an anonymous function inside another function, but without calling the parent function. Because calling the parent function will produce errors.

Parent function:

```
function onloadCallback() {
  grecaptcha.render("recaptchaHolder", {
    "size": "invisible",
    "sitekey": "1Lcsvh53yhsd5312hhsg554dfhs098bbeyi_Hv",
    "callback": function(resp) {
      $("zendesk-ticketing-form").attr("grecaptcha", resp)
    }
  });
}
```

I want to call this:

```
function(resp){$("zendesk-ticketing-form").attr("grecaptcha",resp)}
```

I'm using Java Selenium to do this..

I tried this:

```
 js.executeScript("onloadCallback()(\"" + responseToken + "\")");
```

but it produces an error because its calling onloadCallback (The parent function) before trying to access the anonymous function that's within.

Any ideas?

Comment: if `sitekey` is a real key, then substitute it with something that's not real.

Comment: for privacy purposes? I edited it

Comment: yeah, exactly - Stack Overflow questions (and answers) are public, so displaying a key spells trouble. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly invoke a function in the context you want to but you can extract the function to the outer scope and then use it internally and globally as well.

Assuming you have a situation like;

```js
function a() {
  b('some-name', {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
    c: function(a, b) {
      console.log('i was finally called', a, b);        
    }
  })
}

// turn it into something like

function functionForC(a, b) {
  console.log('i was finally called', a, b);        
}

function a() {
  b('some-name', {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
    c: functionForC
  })
}
```

I would suggest moving that function out of the scope of the function & then using at as a reference inside it as shown below;

This way your current functionality is preserved & you can easily access `functionForC()` directly

Comment: The problem is that the function is in a website.. im trying to execute it using java..
ex: js.executeScript("functionName()");

Comment: that is not possible in this context.

Comment: is there a way to do what ever is in the anonymous function?
{$("zendesk-ticketing-form").attr("grecaptcha",resp)}

Comment: like this?
js.executeScript("document.getElementByTagName('zendesk-ticketing-form').setAttribute(\"grecaptcha\", \"" + responseToken + "\");");

Answer (score 0):

Just executed what was inside :)

```
        js.executeScript("$(\"zendesk-ticketing-form\").attr(\"grecaptcha\",\"" + responseToken + "\")");
```

Thanks